# ACE Editor, Add and update multiple cursors in document with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, ace-editor

I'm trying to create a real-time collaboration session using ACE editor and socket.io.

I'm transmitting the cursor position, row and column to all listening clients.

How can i add and update multiple cursors on all connected ACE clients?

This is what i got on ace:

```
Collaborate.editor.getSession().selection.on('changeCursor', function(e) {

console.log(Collaborate.editor.selection.getCursor());
              Collaborate.socket.emit('cursorchange',Collaborate.editor.selection.getCursor());

});
```

And this is what i got going on with socket.io:

socket.on('cursorchange',function (data) {

```
    socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('cursorusermove', socket.username, data);


});
```

1. How do i add another cursor to the document of all listening clients.
2. For some reason i get multiple socket calls and an endless loop. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addSelectionMarker` is for drawing default selection markers it doesn't allow setting color.
Use `addMarker` directly or use `addDynamicMarker` see [search_highlight](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/search_highlight.js) for an example

> I cant seem to deselect the previous selection leaving the editors filled with tons of 
>   selections and cursors.

either call `removeMarker` or modify old range.

you can also try to use code from http://www.firepad.io/examples/#ace-FHNSp4Vai7